# Salesforce Error on formula - I am getting a syntax error on a formula I am trying to write

Tags: community

I am getting an error of "Error: Syntax error. Extra Account.NF_LSL4LPredictive2016TotalScore__c" I am trying to look at multiple fields and if any of them contain a "0" or "-1" then I want to bring back the value that is in the Account field NF_LSL4LPredictive2016TotalScore_c

```
IF(OR(NF_LSDemandGenPersonScore__c = -1,NF_LSDemandGenPersonScore__c = 0,NF_LSMarketingOpsPersonScore__c = -1,NF_LSMarketingOpsPersonScore__c = 0,NF_LSSalesOperationsPersonScore__c = -1,NF_LSSalesOperationsPersonScore__c = 0)),"Account.NF_LSL4LPredictive2016TotalScore__c",
NULL
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `)` in your formula. I cleaned it up in an editor, it was highlighted immediately.

```
IF(
    OR(
        NF_LSDemandGenPersonScore__c = -1,
        NF_LSDemandGenPersonScore__c = 0,
        NF_LSMarketingOpsPersonScore__c = -1,
        NF_LSMarketingOpsPersonScore__c = 0,
        NF_LSSalesOperationsPersonScore__c = -1,
        NF_LSSalesOperationsPersonScore__c = 0
    // Extra ) was here
    ),
    "Account.NF_LSL4LPredictive2016TotalScore__c",
NULL
)
```

If you meant to show a field value, do not use *quotes*, as that will show literally the text you place there.

```
IF(
    OR(
        NF_LSDemandGenPersonScore__c = -1,
        NF_LSDemandGenPersonScore__c = 0,
        NF_LSMarketingOpsPersonScore__c = -1,
        NF_LSMarketingOpsPersonScore__c = 0,
        NF_LSSalesOperationsPersonScore__c = -1,
        NF_LSSalesOperationsPersonScore__c = 0
    ),
    Account.NF_LSL4LPredictive2016TotalScore__c,
NULL
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much I am new and learning as I go, what editor did you use? Again appreciate all your help!

Comment: @KateMurray I use VS Code. You can download and install for free, it's great for catching simple problems like this.

Comment: Thank you! Doing so now